# Is it a bug in System.Globalization.Info with en-BE CultureInfo

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I tried to get the `RegionInfo` from `CultureInfo` using the code below:

```
RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(currentCulture.LCID);
languageCode = region.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

It worked quite ok but when I have the `currentCulture` with language code `en-BE`, the `RegionInfo` return `"Ethiopian Birr"` which is wrong.

[image]

Do you know if there are any known bugs about this issue.

Tried to run it with nl-BE and fr-BE, it returned correct RegionInfo with DisplayName = Belgium

[nl-BE, fr-BE return correct results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2PoX.png)

Best regards,

Comment: "*the RegionInfo return "Ethiopian Birr" which is wrong.*" -- why is this wrong?

Comment: What else do you expect?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: I'd say that using LCID is going to be problematic because a lot of the installed cultures shares a LCID of 4096, including en-BE (English Belgium).

Comment: I agree with Lasse. If your LCID is 4096 (which is the case for en-BE) this means [LOCALE_CUSTOM_UNSPECIFIED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). Use `new RegionInfo(currentCulture.Name)` instead.

Comment: @canton7 I think it should return something related to Belgium

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen@ckuri I will give a try. Thanks :)